# How do I check for a Bingo?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm creating a bingo-like game. And in my case, the 'Bingo-card' contains 25 numbers. How do I check if there is a 'chance' and a 'bingo' on one of the 3 (horizontal, vertical or diagonal) ways?

Bingo array

```
int[,] lost_numbers = { { 1, 0, 1,  0 , 1 },
                        { 1, 1, 0,  0 , 1 },
                        { 1, 0, 1,  0 , 1 },
                        { 0, 0, 0, [1], 1 },
                        { 0, 1, 1,  0 , 0 }
 };
```

Vertical look

```
        int sumV = 0;
        for (int colnr = 0; colnr < 4; colnr++)
        {
            for (int rownr = 0; rownr < numRows; rownr++)
            {
                sumV += lost_numbers[rownr, colnr];

                if (sumV == 1) // sum of the column
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < numRows; y++)
                    {
                        if (lost_numbers[colnr, y] == 1)
                        {
                            // here change ??
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            sumV = 0;
        }
```

The problem is that you have to have a look if the Sum = 4 when the loop is finished, otherwise every 1 is a change. How do I solve this?

Comment: [Bingo Algorithm in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34025403/4934172)

Comment: My card's are already generated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simple. You could do it in two steps.

In step 1 you just check IF there is bingo or a chance in some of the lines. You suggesting calculation the sum, that should work just fine.

Only if step 1 found something then you would visit that line(s) again and find out where exactly your chance is.

Comment: I succeded the first step. But my issue is how do I check when loop is ended and not at the first 1.

Comment: Took a while but succeeded. Thanks!